# <> Xml lost when converting To and From 64BaseString

Tags: c#, .net, xml, encryption

I have this simple Xml file

```
<Root>
    <Licence Name="My name" Age="23"/>
</Root>
```

During my encryption and decryption process, I'm using `ToBase64String()` and`FromBase64String()` methods, but it does not seam to work, when I try to decrypt the file, the **<>** witch limit my **Licence** element are lost. here's the result after encryption and decryption :

```
<Root>&lt;Licence Name="My name" Age="23" /&gt;</Root>
```

Here is my code

```
//Encrypt
private void bnEncrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var xDoc = XElement.Load(@"C:\Opticien\Lic.xml");
        var data = xDoc.Element("Licence").ToString();

        var dataByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        var dataEncrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(dataByte);

        xDoc.SetValue(dataEncrypted);
        xDoc.Save(@"C:\Opticien\Lic.xml");
        memoEdit1.Text = xDoc.ToString();
}

//Decrypt
private void bnDecrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var xDoc = XElement.Load(@"C:\Opticien\Lic.xml");
        var data = xDoc.Value;

        var dataByte = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
        var dataDecrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataByte);

        xDoc.SetValue(dataDecrypted);
        xDoc.Save(@"C:\Opticien\Lic.xml");
        memoEdit1.Text = xDoc.ToString();
}
```

Comment: `I'm trying to encrypt it using ToBase64String() method, and then decrypt it using FromBase64String() method,` - and you call this encryption? Wow! Hopefully your XML won't fall into the hands of malicious users as they will simply laugh :-)

Comment: @Darin Dimitriv : I have my encryption and decryption methods, I just did not post them. I'm just using the ToBase64String() ... during my encryption and decryption.

Comment: "Encrypt" and "decrypt" seem a little strong here!

Comment: Base64 is an *encoding*, not an encryption.  It is not intended for security, but for 'armouring' non-ASCII formats to allow them to be transmitted over ASCII only links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using SetValue in `xDoc.SetValue(dataDecrypted);`. This sets the text of the `<Root>` node, escaping any special characters like the '<' and '>' characters.

Instead, use [XElement.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb468714.aspx) to create a new XElement based in the decoded (rather than decrypted) string.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `xDoc.SetValue(dataDecrypted);` you need to use this code:

```
xDoc.FirstNode.ReplaceWith(XElement.Parse(dataDecrypted));
```